# Python - Mechanize not opening the browser

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to find a company on a website and then click the link the search returns. After working a while to debug the code - it turned out my capitalization was off - the script runs through smoothly without any errors but it does not open the link in the browser like I thought it would.

Here is the code:

```
import webbrowser
import csv
import mechanize
import string

br = mechanize.Browser()

def open_page(url):
webbrowser.open(url)


def name_to_url(name):
    words = name.split(" ")
    url = "http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/search/results?Name="
    end_of_url = "&Type=0&IncludeNlsp=True&Pro=True"
    for word in words:
        url += "%s+" % word
    url += "%s" % end_of_url

    return url


with open('/home/seb/company-list/data/test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        company_name = string.capwords(row[0])
        url_go = name_to_url(company_name)
        br.open(url_go)
        br.find_link(text=company_name)
        req = br.click_link(text=company_name)
        br.open(req)
```

The URL it leads to is correct 100% (triple-checked in Pycharm) and the company_name is also correct.

Comment: Can you give us a sample test.csv file so we can test the script ?

Comment: In `name_to_url` you could do: `url += '+'.join(words + [end_of_url])` instead of the `for` loop plus final append, the results should be exactly the same.

Comment: You never call `open_page`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mechanize open Url python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916188/mechanize-open-url-python)