# BeautifulSoup4 find or select string begining with substring containing non alpha numerics

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup4 to scrape a page containing the following element of interest:

```
<span class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)" data-reactid="279">170.55</span>
```

I have tried the following, none of which work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = Beautiful(fetch_page_html())

#Attempt 1
elem = soup.select("span[class^=Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)]") 

#Attempt 2
elem = soup.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^<span class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

**[[Addendum]]**

Please, don't advise me to use another scraper library because of XYZ, that's not what I'm asking here, I know there are other scraping libraries out there, and bs4 is probably getting long in the tooth now, but this is what I'm used to, and I need to patch an existing script TODAY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class="c1 c2 c3"` is equivalent to having multiple classes. You can try like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsp
import requests 

res = requests.get("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM/options?p=IBM&straddle=false&date=1486080000").content
soup = bsp(res, 'lxml')
l = soup.select('div.D(ib).Fw(200).Mend(20px) span.Mb(-4px).Fw(b).Fz(36px)')[0]
print l.text
```

Output:

```
170.55
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. It returns an empty list. I'm beginning to think bs4 is past its due date. Starting to look at Scrapy - DESPITE what I said in my OP.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli If you can provide the link, it can be tested.

Comment: here's the [link](http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM/options?p=IBM&straddle=false&date=1486080000). I'm trying to fetch the price **170.55** (and as it so happens, also the timestamp **4:00PM EST** - but that's probably another question).

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Check now.

Comment: OK, it works now **if I copy and paste your code**, but if I obtain the page html using `mechanize.open(url)`, then the select fails (if even I specify the lxml parser in the soup constructor). Something very odd is going on. anyway, I can run with this and make the minor changes required to my code. Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527862/python-mechanize-wont-open-these-sites

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133804/discussion-between-homunculus-reticulli-and-mygz).

Answer (score 0):

```
elem = soup.select("span[class^='Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)']")
```

or

```
elem = soup.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^Fw\(b\) Fz\(36px\) Mb\(-4px\)'))
```

[CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

notic the `""` in the value:

[image]

[regular expression](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

If you pass in a regular expression object, Beautiful Soup will filter against that regular expression using its `search()` method.

```
import bs4

html = '<span class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)" data-reactid="279">170.55</span>'

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

sel = soup.select("span[class^='Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)']") 

reg = soup.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^Fw\(b\) Fz\(36px\) Mb\(-4px\)'))
```

out:

```
<span class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)" data-reactid="279">170.55</span>
<span class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px)" data-reactid="279">170.55</span>
```

Comment: With first one, I get `ValueError: Unsupported or invalid CSS selector: "span[class^='Fw(b)"`, with second one, elem is `None`. BTW, I'm running this in Python 3.5, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Homunculus Reticulli miss a `'` in the end

Comment: Try using a longer html string containing the span I am searching for - I think you'll find that your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Homunculus Reticulli  you should post the logger code in the question, not in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
elem = soup.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^Fw\(b\) Fz\(36px\) Mb\(-4px\)'))

Comment: elem is `None`. I think you have to test this with the span I'm looking for, hidden in a larger HTML document.